# How to do some processing after response on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a Java server running on GAE to support an Android app.

When the app is launched it makes a request to the server - that request should return as quickly as possible.  That request should also trigger a few seconds of secondary processing - secondary in that it is not necessary for the response, so I would like it do occur after the request is complete.

Here are the options I'm considering for how to do that:

- The most obvious solution is for the app to **perform a second request** when the first one completes.  This seems rather wasteful as there will usually be no data to send or receive.  In cases where the secondary  processing does yield some additional data for the client (20%) I could just as well send it via GCM now that  GCM supports payloads.
- [**DeferredTasks**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Deferred_Tasks) sound perfect, but since they are implemented on top of task queues, I guess they suffer from the same issues as task queues.
- [**TaskQueues**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) sound suitable too, but a little reading suggests that their timing is highly variable - there is often a considerable delay.  As I mention above, in 20% of cases my secondary processing will yield some additional data to send to the client, to be displayed to the user.
  If my task were executed within 10 seconds, 80% of the time, that would be fine, but it sounds like that is not the case. [edit: sorry, didn't mean to suggest that the remaining 20% don't matter - I still want them to occur within 20-30s, e.g. while user is still in the app.]

Is there some way I can configure my app such that a push task queue gets reasonably high priority without incurring undue costs?

- **Async Url Fetch**.  It seems to me that if I do an async url fetch to one of my own URL's, just before completing the initial request, then this would serve my purpose.  The main negative I can think of that this may cause GAE to launch a new instance of my app since it is trying to handle the new request before the initial request is complete.  I'd rather have my secondary processing happen in serial with my initial request for the sake of efficiency and cost.
- **Threads** are not an option AFAIK.  Threads spawned in my request handler can not live beyond the life of the request handler itself.

So, which of these options (or others?) would best suite my purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taskqueues are the best way to get background processing like you want.  Reports of long execuction delays are somewhat exaggerated.  You can review [live execution timing measurements](https://code.google.com/status/appengine/) (click a Taskqueue icon) to see if it's within your requirements.

For the last several days it shows that tasks are typically executed within 300 ms.  Eyeballing that data suggests about 90% of tasks are executed within 3 seconds.

There are occasional delays, but for data that's "not necessary for the response" I've found Taskqueues to work very well.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that I could get TQ handling latency data from that page - whoops.  Very useful data.  I can see the high variability that others have referred to, and can appreciate that this would make them unsuitable for most use case where the user is waiting for the data, but for my purposes I think this is acceptable (though not ideal).

Answer (score 3):

Task queues best suit your purpose on app engine. I think the only other way to meet all of your requirements is to use your own servers, or something like EC2/GCE.

An async url fetch is risky because if it fails for some reason it will not be resubmitted. The task queues can be configured at a high velocity, decreasing the risk of a task taking a long time to be scheduled. Threads are not an option: when a request is completed, no RPCs can be submitted from it (i.e., if you have another thread running after your request is done, that thread won't be able to do anything useful).

Comment: Please read the issues link noted by voscausa. Using task queue parameters to configure a high throughput TQ will not affect the  issue of unpredictable TQ starts. In general you can rely on a high throughput task starting immediately. There will, however, be times where a task is delayed for minutes. No one knows why. This was a very big discussion in Google Groups initiated by Vlad about this. GAE engineers have never provided any insights. I myself advocated in the groups for one high-priority queue that could be relied upon. Perhaps with the new app/server architecture?

Comment: I agree with most of the points in this answer, but not the conclusion.  The points made by stevep and the issue noted by voscausa reinforce my concern that TQ do not have reliable timing.  I've made an edit to my question to make my timing requirements clearer.

Comment: I agree that my answer to use task queues is not great. However, it is the **best** you can do currently on app engine. If you want all of your requirements to be met, you need to use something that is not app engine.

Comment: Just wanted to add a bit more since what I wrote above might be read too pessimistically. I rely extensively on task queues. They almost always run very quickly. It is only the rare occasion where a task will wait minutes before starting. tl;dnr task queues are very valuable and useful. Recognize that very infrequently a task will not start very quickly, and plan accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Star this one : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4901

Can't you use background threads / threading : static java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory    backgroundThreadFactory()
Returns a ThreadFactory that will create threads that are independent of the current request.

From the docs : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager

Comment: No, threads are not an option.  Threads are not allowed beyond the life of the request.  I'll update my question to address that.  But thanks for the suggestion and I'll star that issue.

Comment: But you can use a backend (thread) : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/

Comment: Yeah but backends sound very heavy duty (and rather expensive) for what I'm trying to do.